# Python: os.system(ping) argument not working?

Tags: python, arguments, ping, function, os.system

I am trying to make a def statement that uses os.system(ping) with a variable, and it does not want to take the variable:

```
import os

def myping(myip):
    print(myip)
    ip1 = os.system("ping -c 1 myip")
    print(ip1)
myping("127.0.0.1")
```

This returns a code of 512 (fail, rather than a 0, which is success) and then "ping: unknown host myip".  Depending on how I format the myip in the os.system statement I can also get a 256 with another error.  I have tried various ways of formatting it, including quotation marks, parentheses, percent signs and such, and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I can tell I am making it think I want to scan for myip (literal string).  What syntax do I have wrong here?  Thanks.

By the way, print(myip) within the def statement does give me 127.0.0.1.

Comment: `ip1 = os.system("ping -c 1 {}".format(myip))`

Comment: This is so funny. I came back to look at this question 2 years later because it had a couple thousand views, and right away I could see what was wrong. Experience! Thanks for the help, guys! I needed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to get the value of `myip` into the argument to `os.system`:

```
ip1 = os.system('ping -c 1 {}'.format(myip))
```

or (old style, deprecated in python 3.1):

```
ip1 = os.system("ping -c 1 %s" % myip)
```

Comment: You should favor the second approach. `%s` style string interpolation is deprecated in favor of `.format`, as noted in the Python documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: On Windows 7 and Python 3.3 the return code is 1 without regard to whether the IP is reachable or not.

Comment: Thank you so much--that worked!  (specifically, the second method.)

Answer (score 0):

another option is

```py
ip = os.system(f'ping -c 1 {myip}')
```